# Need help understanding this: $A$ is a subring of the ring $B$, $B$ is finite over $A$ if $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

So I have this property:

$A$ is a subring of the ring $B$.

$B$ is finite over $A$ if $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module.

I'm having issues understanding it would $A = B$ because from my understanding of modules any element from the ring outside the module multiplied by an element in the module would give another element in the module. So how can $B$ be generated by the elements in module $A$ unless $A = B$.

Comment: The module is $B$, while $A$ is the ring of coefficients.

Comment: oh my god i feel so dumb thank you I was sitting here so confused

Comment: Here is an example. To start, $\Bbb R$ is a subring of $\Bbb C$, right? Now, $\Bbb C$ *is finite over* $\Bbb R$ because $\Bbb C$, seen as an $\Bbb R$-module, is generated by $1$ and $i$.